# T-SQL : Cleaning up data, merging rows into columns

Tags: sql-server, recursion

I'm trying to clean up some Active Directory data in SQL Server. I have managed to read the raw LFD file into a table. Now I need to clean up some attributes where values are spread out over multiple rows. I can identify records that need to be appended to the prior record by the fact the have a leading space.

Example:

```
ID        Record                     IsPartOfPrior
3114      memberOf:                        0
3115       CN=Sharepoint-Members-home      1
3116      memberOf:                        0
3117       This is                         1
3118       part of the                     1
3119       next line.                      1
```

Ultimately, I would like to have the following table generated:

```
ID          Record
3114        memberOf:CN=Sharepoint-Members-home
3116        memberOf:This is part of the next line
```

I could write it through a cursor, setting variables, working with temp tables and populating a table. But there has to be a set based (maybe recursive?) approach to this?

I could use the STUFF method to combine various rows together, but how am I about to group the various sets together? I'm thinking that I first have to define groupID's per record, and then stuff them together per groupID?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hint : Use `STUFF`

Comment: If you are reading the data from AD presumably in code, then why don't you concatenate the values before saving to the db?

Answer (score 0):

Batch with comments below. Should work starting with **SQL Server 2008**.

```
--Here I emulate your table
DECLARE @yourtable TABLE (ID int, Record nvarchar(max), IsPartOfPrior bit)

INSERT INTO @yourtable VALUES                   
(3114,'memberOf:',0),(3115,'CN=Sharepoint-Members-home',1),(3116,'memberOf:',0),(3117,'This is',1),(3118,'part of the',1),(3119,'next line.',1)

--Getting max ID
DECLARE @max_id int 

SELECT @max_id = MAX(ID)+1
FROM @yourtable

--We get next prior for each prior record
--And use STUFF and FOR XML PATH to build new Record
SELECT  y.ID,
        y.Record + b.Record as Record
FROM @yourtable y
OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 ID as NextPrior
        FROM @yourtable 
        WHERE IsPartOfPrior = 0 and y.ID < ID
        ORDER BY ID ASC
    ) as t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT STUFF((
        SELECT ' '+Record
        FROM @yourtable
        WHERE ID > y.ID and ID < ISNULL(t.NextPrior,@max_id)
        ORDER BY id ASC
        FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,'') as Record
) as b
WHERE y.IsPartOfPrior = 0
```

The output:

```
ID          Record
----------- -----------------------------------------
3114        memberOf:CN=Sharepoint-Members-home
3116        memberOf:This is part of the next line.
```

This will work if `ID` are numeric and ascending.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option **if 2012+**

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[Record] varchar(50),[IsPartOfPrior] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values
 (3114,'memberOf:',0)
,(3115,'CN=Sharepoint-Members-home',1)
,(3116,'memberOf:',0)
,(3117,'This is',1)
,(3118,'part of the',1)
,(3119,'next line.',1)

;with cte as (
    Select *,Grp = sum(IIF([IsPartOfPrior]=0,1,0)) over (Order By ID)
     From @YourTable
)
Select ID
      ,Record  = Stuff((Select ' ' +Record From cte Where Grp=A.Grp Order by ID For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
 From (Select Grp,ID=min(ID)from cte Group By Grp   ) A
```

**Returns**

```
ID      Record
3114    memberOf: CN=Sharepoint-Members-home
3116    memberOf: This is part of the next line.
```

**If it Helps with the Visualization, the cte Produces:**

```
ID      Record                      IsPartOfPrior   Grp  << Notice Grp Values
3114    memberOf:                   0               1
3115    CN=Sharepoint-Members-home  1               1
3116    memberOf:                   0               2
3117    This is                     1               2
3118    part of the                 1               2
3119    next line.                  1               2
```

Comment: Please, note, that `IIF` works with SQL Server 2012 and up.

Comment: @gofr1 Very true, I should have qualified that.  (made the notation)